# OneToOne Relationship issue

Tags: django, django-models

I am implementing a stand-alone `'like'` class(not just as part of Question class), so that I will be able to create Notification class later including new likes, followings and other social stuff.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    like = models.OneToOneField('Like',related_name='like_QUESTION',null=True, blank=True)

class Like(models.Model):
    what_post_is_liked = models.OneToOneField('Question', related_name='what_post_is_liked_LIKE')
    who_liked = models.OneToOneField('UserProfile', related_name='who_liked_LIKE')
    whom = models.OneToOneField('UserProfile', related_name='whom_LIKE')
```

How do I get properties('what_post_is_liked') of class Like through 'like' property of `Question` class? According to the documentation on OneToOne relationships I should just write properties of Like class just after `'like'` just like this `e.like.who_liked` ?

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(whom=request.user.profile)
for e in questions:
            print(e.like)
```

Although 'Like' object exists, 'e.like' returns None, which means that 'like' doesn't automatically inherits 'Like' newly created object ?

```
like = Like(whom=a,who_liked=b,what_post_is_liked=c)
like.save()
```

I've got into a total mass. Could someone please explain how it actually works? How can I make automatically copied/inheritable and get 'Like' properties through like of 'Question' class?

Comment: @e4c5 it's edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneToOneField probably isn't the right one to user here. With a one-to-one relationship each `Question` can have at most one `Like` so what you are looking for is a `ForeignKey` and that [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) should be in your Like model. So we have

```
class Question(models.Model):
    marks = models.IntegerField() # whatever question related field
    # there's not like here.

class Like(models.Model):
    what_post_is_liked = models.ForeignKey('Question', related_name='what_post_is_liked_LIKE')
    who_liked = models.OneToOneField('UserProfile', related_name='who_liked_LIKE')
    whom = models.OneToOneField('UserProfile', related_name='whom_LIKE')
```

Then you can do

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(like__whom=request.user.profile)
```

If you want your like object to be linkable to many different types of objects other than just questions, you will have to use a [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), which is lot more powerfull (and a little more complex)

Comment: ok, I got the foreign key thing, and how to handle with retrieving related Like object information from Question object ?

Comment: that's a different question but the answer is question.like_set.all()